# How to make Vect n Int an instance of Monoid

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, dependent-type, idris

In Idris, `Vect n a` is a datatype representing a vector of n length containing items of type a. Imagine I have a function:

```
foo : Int -> Vect 4 Int
foo n = [n-1, n, n+1, n*4]
```

The body of the function is not important, it could be anything that returns a vector of 4 Ints. Now, I want to use this function with concatMap as follows:

```
bar : Vect n Int -> Vect (4*n) Int
bar vals = concatMap foo vals
```

Bar is a function that takes an Int vector of length n and returns ones of length 4*n.

The type signature of concatMap is:

```
Prelude.Foldable.concatMap : Foldable t => Monoid m => (a -> m) -> t a -> m
```

And hence if I try to compile bar, I get the error:

```
 When elaborating right hand side of bar:
     Can't resolve type class Monoid (Vect (plus n (plus n (plus n (plus n 0)))) Int)
```

This means Vect n Int isn't an instance of monoid. To make it an instance of monoid, I need to implement:

```
Prelude.Algebra.neutral : Monoid a => a
```

Unfortunately however I'm not sure how to do this. List implements monoid, as follows:

```
instance Monoid (List a) where
    neutral = []
```

But if I try to implement monoid with neutral = [] for Vect n Int, I receive the error:

```
 When elaborating right hand side of Prelude.Algebra.Vect n Int instance of Prelude.Algebra.Monoid, method neutral:
 |   Can't unify
 |           Vect 0 Int
 |   with
 |           Vect n Int
 |   
 |   Specifically:
 |           Can't unify
 |                   0
 |           with
 |                   n
```

So I was wondering, how would I go about implementing monoid for Vect?

Comment: Concatenation affects vector length, so `Vect n a` can't be a monoid, since `n` needs to be doubled in the result. You need a custom `concat : Vect n (Vect m a) -> Vect (n*m) a`, which probably needs a `_++_ : Vect n a -> Vect m a -> Vect (n+m) a` and some arithmetic lemmas such as `n*m + m = (succ n)*m`.

Comment: @chi There is a [`concat`](http://www.idris-lang.org/docs/prelude_doc/docs/Prelude.Vect.html#Prelude.Vect.concat) function in the stdlib of idris.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't implement a monoid such that you are able to write down that expression using `concatMap`. Think about the signature of `concatMap`:

```
(Foldable t, Monoid m) => (a -> m) -> t a -> m
```

Note that the `m` must be *the same `Monoid`* in the both the return type of the functional argument `(a -> m)` and the return type of the whole function. However *this is not the case* for `Vect n a`. Consider the expression:

```
concatMap foo vals
```

Here `foo` will have a type of `a -> Vect 4 a`, and the result of `concatMap` that you want is of type `Vect (4*n) a` where `n` is the length of the original vector. But this cannot fit the `concatMap` type because you have an application of `concatMap` that requires a type like:

```
(Foldable t, Monoid m, Monoid m1) => (a -> m) -> t a -> m1
```

where the result monoid and the value returned by the function can be different types, while `concatMap` imposes you to use the same type.

`[a]` and `Vect n a` are completely different because `[]` does *not* include the length in the type, and this allows you to write a `concatMap` function. In fact this allows you to make a `Monoid` instance for `[]` and concatenation as binary operator.

When you start attaching the length to a type this possibility vanishes because you cannot mix different lengths anymore and thus `Vect n a` do *not* form a monoid for concatenation.
The concatenation operator becomes of type `a -> b -> c` in the general case, and in particular it's type for `Vect`s is `Vect n a -> Vect m a -> Vect (n+m) a`, which is clearly different from its type for lists: `[a] -> [a] ->[a]`.

---

This said, the error you reported is due to the fact that when writing an instance for the `Monoid` class of `Vect n a` the value of `neutral` must be of type `Vect n a` but `[]` is of type `Vect 0 a`.

However you can create a *different* instance for the `Monoid` type class over `Vect n a`.
If the elements of such a vector are monoids then you can create the monoid of such vectors.

In this case he `neutral` vector must be of length `n`, and the only sensible value that you can give to its elements is the `neutral` of the elements `Monoid`.
Basically you want the `neutral` of `Vect n a` to be `replicate n neutral`.

The binary operation for the `Monoid` would then be the element-wise application of the operation between the elements.

So the instance would look something like:

```
instance Monoid a => Monoid (Vect n a) where
    neutral = replicate n neutral

instance Semigroup a => Semigroup (Vect n a) where
    Nil <+> Nil = Nil
    (x :: xs) <+> (y :: ys) = (x <+> y) :: (xs <+> ys)
```

Unfortunately I'm not an Idris user/programmer so I can't tell you exactly how to correctly write such code. The above is just an Haskell-like pseudocode to give an idea of the concepts.

Comment: Thank you! Your suggestion for implementing Monoid worked, although now it seems Vect has to implement Semigroup too.

Comment: Well, you can create a `concatMap` that, instead of concatenating the results, it will sum them (or perform any other operation of type `Vect n a -> Vect n a -> Vect n a`). However you will not be able to obtain a `concatMap` where the final length is different from the length of the vects returned by the function applications.

Comment: Good point. Your Semigroup implementation works too, by the way, but as Integers do not implement Semigroup, concatMap still fails with the original error (no implementation of monoid for Vect n Int).

Comment: @LogicChains Well, that is the most general instance. Instead of creating an instance for `Semigroup a => Semigroup (Vect n a)` you can simply create an instance for `Semigroup (Vect n Int)` and use `+` or `*` in the definitions for the vector's `<+>` operation. In particular you'd have `(x :: xs) <+> (y :: ys) = x + y :: (xs <+> ys)`. To implement `Monoid` you can simply specify `replicate n 0` if you wanted addition or `replicate n 1` if you wanted multiplication. In Haskell you could also simply implement `Semigroup` for `Int`; not sure whether Idris allows "orphan instances".

Comment: I implemented Semigroup and Monoid for Int, and finally get a more informative error message:
"    When elaborating an application of function Prelude.Foldable.concatMap:
             Can't unify
                     Int -> Vect (fromInteger 4) Int
             with
                     Int -> Vect (plus n (plus n (plus n (plus n 0)))) Int`
             
`             Specifically:
                     Can't unify
                             4
                     with
                             plus n (plus n (plus n (plus n 0)))"